# Multiple Components listening via eventlistener

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I was wondering why you're not allowed to have multiple similar eventListeners on a single node? I imagine the case where I have multiple partials of the same type that use a single node to communicate with eachother through CustomEvents. But that doesnt seem to be working because they do all share the same EventListener and thus only one of them is able to listen and process the event.

Why is that?

Thanks!

EDIT: little code snippet:

I have

```
node.addEventListener("customEvent", this.func, false);
```

and

```
node.addEventListener("customEvent", this.func, false);
```

in two different places and this.func points to the same function but in different contextes and would eventually trigger different things. But the second listener never gets called because for some reason this something seems to assumes that their the same probably because the signature is alike or whatever.

EDIT2: I'm basically referring to this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners

Comment: Calm down, add the code that failed.

Comment: Please add more, where is this comming from. At this moment it's `window`, You are using this in a function.

Comment: What you mean by window? Unfortunately the full code snippet is like 1000 LOC which wouldn't help clarifying things much. I just have this node.addEventListener("customEvent", this.func, false); defined in 2 closures. node is pointing to the same external node for both. this.func has the same function definition in both closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach multiple similar event handlers to a node by using addEventListener.

```
node.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1)}, false);
node.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(2)}, false);
```

Should give an alert twice.
When you assign anonymous function this works.

However you can assign multiple listeners referring to the same function and event by using bind.

```
var a = this.func.bind();
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", a, false);   
var b = this.func.bind();
document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", b, false);
```

This will alert twice. Since the function wrapper is different, it's being treated as an unique event.

You can't assign an event handler twice through node.onclick, because it's a property. When you assign it twice it will just overwrite the first handler. Event listeners were invented to cope with this.

Comment: Yeah that does work because the function block is different. But add the same eventListener twice in two places and the latter want be called ever.

Comment: You mean adding `node.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1)}, false)` twice to a node? Because `node.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1)}, false)` and `node2.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1)}, false)` work.

Comment: See my edit. :-) Or is node2 and node pointing to the same node?

Comment: Nope node2 is a different node, however with this example it will still work if it was the same node, since I'm creating two anonymous functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners i was referring to this.

Comment: Yes I figured that out long ago. About the binding part. My updated solution works however. Those are cancelable to.

Comment: Bind did the trick, thanks! Though i still don't really get what contexts bind() is clearing because the contexts are already set correctly to the local closure.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can add multiple listeners. But, honestly, I dont like this approach. In most of the cases, you only need to trigger 1 interface/object (you are adding a overhead, logic for multiple interfaces where only one is used).

I like more the Android approach: setOn....Event (looks like JS is this way) instead of addActionListener(...) of Java.

When you need multiple triggers, you could override like:

```
 obj.setOnEvent(function() {
    doTheOtherEventTrigger();
    doOneMoreEventTrigger();
    ...
 }
```

Comment: You do know the OP is asking a question about JavaScript event listeners on html nodes, not Java.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said " (looks like JS is this way) "

Comment: But then this is a non useful answer. What works in Java isn't automatically going to work in JS.

Comment: @user3558040 yeah i struggle a little how this applies to my question. :-)